# How to have multiple ProductIDs in an order MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new to all of this. I have database set up for an online store with the following tables: Customer,Product,Order,Order_Details and Sales. What I'm having trouble with is the Order_details table. For example if a person orders more than one product I can't insert more than one productID. Sorry if I explained this weirdly, any help is appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY1xa.jpg

Comment: Order_Details needs it's own primary key.

Comment: you probably want to set productID and customerID to something not Unique as this will prevent you from having many customers ordering the same product and many products by customer

Answer (score 1):

You have the orderID set as a primary key in the order_details table. Remove primary key from that field. Introduce a id column to the order_details table with primary key set.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have set the productID as a unique index which should not be the case.

Check indexes and see if the productID is a unique index. If it is i would suggest you delete the unique index property for productID

[image: Check indexes and see if the productID is a unique index. If it is i would suggest you delete the unique index property for productID]

You may as-well try to have another column for order_number. i.e. generate a unique number for each order but dont set order_number column as a unique column

**FOR INSTANCE** A cart of five ordered product but with same order_number so that you may group the result as one single cart